# Find which span is edited inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote some HTML:

```
<div id="contentbox" contenteditable="true"><span value="1">Hello</span><span value="2">Stack</span><span value="3">over</span> flow</div>
```

And jQuery

```
$("#contentbox").live("keyup",function(event){alert(jQuery(this).attr('value'));}}});
```

I need to get the value of span which has been edited inside the content.

Comment: You haven't really asked a question here... What exactly is the problem? (other than the syntax error)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the code you have provided.

Firstly, you have a syntax error but I'm going to attribute that to a copy paste error when creating this post.

You have placed the `contenteditable` attribute on the div wrapper - so this will make **all** of the text editable...

Other than that, you are referencing `this` within the event callback - but `this` will reference the `div` element and not the inner span. So...

1. You'll want to change the code in your callback to look like this:

   `alert( $(this).find("span").attr('value') )`
2. Span elements don't have a value attribute... You are looking for the `text()` function to extract the textual content of the element.

   `alert( $(this).find("span").text() )`

Note that there are more than one span elements within `#contentbox`, so the text value will be the content of **both** spans.

[Here is a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kprL6/) - I've used `console.log` because...well.. I don't really like alerts :P